# What is The HCS class?

Tags: c#, hoops

Currently im Working on Code That uses the HCS Class. Can Anyone Tell Me What this class is and where I can find documentation about it?

for Example

```
HCS.Open_Segment(path);
```

or

```
HCS.Begin_Contents_Search
```

I think it has something to do with Hoops from the Company TechSoft3d. But i cant find anything about this class.

Any Help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Begin_Contents_Search So, HoopsManager.dll? "3D-Graphik mit HOOPS: Einführung in die Programmierung"? which suggests you might be working with an old version of https://www.techsoft3d.com/products/hoops/visualize/ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HCS is a wrapper class](https://docs.techsoft3d.com/3df/latest/build/general/language_csharp.html#toc_hoops_3dgs_specific) for all HOOPS 3DGS API called from C#.

Answer (score 2):

When you are developing in visual studio you can press F12 to jump to the class.

I don't know the company or software you are using, but normally with niche software it mostly comes with an help file with documentation. Ask your colleagues if there is a stick or cd around which may contain a help file. If you got it over a nuget package you should be able to look something up online.

Comment: Hey Patrick thanks for the answer , I already took a look at the class but it doesn't really helped me to understand the functionality of the commands. also i can't find anything online and my colleagues couldn't help me either with any kind of documentation.

Comment: If there is nothing else and you really need to understand whats written in there, it helped me to decompile the dll. Get https://www.jetbrains.com/de-de/decompiler/ dotPeek and have a look at the decompiled class and try to have a clue about whats written there